# Set ID in PUT method nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

Have code on server

```
apiRoutes.put('/intake', function(req, res)  {
  Intake.findById({id, function(err, intake) {
      if (err)
          res.send(err);
            check : true;
            intake.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Error'});
      }
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful update check state.'});
    });
  }})
});
```

I should set ID value from frontend, but I don't know how I can set it in function. Try this apiRoutes.put('/intake', id, function(req, res), but id is not defined
On front in controller.js:

```
$scope.changeCheck = function(id) {
    console.log(id);
    mService.intake("PUT", $scope.intake, {"action": "put"}, id)
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    }).error(function(err) {
      mService.errorHandler(status);
    });
  };
```

And in services file:

```
 intake : function(method, data, params, value) {

      var endpoint = "";
        switch (params.action) {
        case "put" :
          endpoint = "intake/" + value;
          break;
      }

      return this.request(method, endpoint, data);

    }
```

html

```
<li ng-repeat="intake in intakes">
                    <div class="welcome-box">
                        <div class="welcome-box-content" >
                        <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="intake.check" ng-change="changeCheck(intake.pres_id)" />
                        </label>
                        <span class="drugs"> {{intake.dname}} <br></span> <span class="drugsdescr"><i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"> </i> {{intake.comment}} <i class="fa fa-medkit" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{intake.dose1}}{{intake.dose2}} </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

GET intakes

```
mService.intake("GET", "", {"action" : "get"})
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.intakes = data;
    console.log(data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    mService.errorHandler(status);
  });
```

Comment: What is calling changeCheck in your controller? Is it a button click for example? Can you show that part of the code?

Comment: do you have a list of intakes in your controller? can you add your controller as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you are providing the `id` value in your angular service as part of the url:

```
endpoint = "intake/" + value;
```

which ends up being something like this: `intake/12345`

Since you are not using query params here, the server will expect this as part of the url.

So you have to specify it on the server that `id` is part of the url:

'/intake/**:id**'

```
apiRoutes.put('/intake/:id', function(req, res)  {
   ...
});
```

And then you can get the id value from the request:

```
req.params.id
```

So your put function on the server should look like this:

```
apiRoutes.put('/intake/:id', function(req, res)  {
  var id = req.params.id;      

  Intake.findById({id, function(err, intake) {
      if (err)
          res.send(err);
            check : true;
            intake.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Error'});
      }
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful update check state.'});
    });
  }})
});
```

Comment: it's works! thans!but i can't to get id value of intake. Why? undefined in console

Comment: What do you mean exactly with from intake?